# Plotly Ipywidgets - Interactive - Accessing cross sample for figure output

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, ipywidgets

I am new to plotly and ipywidgets

I want to create a `fig` that has two board of controllers, called `control1` and `control2`. In which, `control1` is a set of widgets allow me to modify to data. Then in `control2` I want to access the data in `control1` for further analysis and display.

The simple solution for this is to combine `control1` and `control2` as a single `control` board. However, I have many filter and this makes it does not look very nice so I want to separate them.

Let me illustrate with a simple data:

```
   comp  year  val1  val2
0     a  2000    89    19
1     a  2001    47    91
2     a  2002    50    25
3     a  2003    63     5
4     a  2004    40    28
5     a  2005    79    53
6     b  2000    26    57
7     b  2001    19    75
8     b  2002    72    89
9     b  2003    74     7
10    b  2004    49    11
11    c  2000    35    62
12    c  2001    50    23
13    c  2002    32    40
14    c  2003    83    60
15    d  2000    91    71
16    d  2001    61    64
17    d  2002    29    80
18    d  2003   100    48
19    d  2004    38    41
20    d  2005    75    38
```

Creating figure by:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Import data
df = pd.read_csv('test_interactive.csv')

# Creating figure
data = go.Scattergl(x=df['val1'],
                    y=df['val2'],
                    mode='markers')
layout = go.Layout(title='Some Title')
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)

# Create `control1` board:
def graph_filter(comp, year):
    # filter by 'comp' and 'year':
    tem = df[(df['comp'] == comp) & (df['year'] == year)]
    
    fig.data[0].x = tem['val1']
    fig.data[0].y = tem['val2']
    
control1 = widgets.interactive(
    graph_filter,
    comp=widgets.Dropdown(
        options=df['comp'].unique(),
        value='a',
        disabeled=False,
        description='Select Comp'),
    year=widgets.Dropdown(
        options=df['year'].unique(),
        value=2000,
        description='Select Year',
        disabeled=False)
)
```

Now I want to create another `control2` which I can access data filter after `control1` for further analysis but I don't know how to.

```
control2 = ???
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is simply set variable modified dataframe in self-defined function to be global variable. That is a quick solution I can think of now.

```
def graph_filter(comp, year):
    # filter by 'comp' and 'year':
    global tem
    tem = df[(df['comp'] == comp) & (df['year'] == year)]
```